# Umbraco Begin Form vs Begin Form

Tags: umbraco7

I've just have a little curiosity about this two code.. Both of them is working but what is the difference?

```
Html.BeginUmbracoForm() vs Html.BeginForm()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BeginUmbracoFrom method helps with determining the correct paths honoring the Umbraco routing conventions, for example you can give it a strongly typed Controller class and it creates the path to the surface controller. This also allows you to refactor more easily

```
Html.BeginUmbracoForm<TestSurfaceController>("PostVals")
```

It has a bunch of different overloads, check them out [here](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/Forms/index-v7)